# How do I indicate transparency in an SVG path in Google Maps API v3?

Tags: google-maps, svg

I've been searching on and off stackoverflow and haven't found the answer, so here goes...

I have a custom SVG image path of a bus (see below) and it's drawing properly and "cutting out" portions that I want transparent as it should, just not the headlights.  I've looked through the SVG path data docs at http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData and must be missing something.  I don't know how (in the path data, or maybe NOT in it) to identify what gets filled and what is part of a transparency mask or non-fill area.  Here's what I'm working with.

```
var busSvg = {
    // Bus body
    // 282 wide... 322 wide with the sides added
    top : 'c-4,-20,-18,-30,-38,-38 c-20,-8,-68,-18,-113,-19 c-35,1,-83,11,-113,19 c-20,8,-34,10,-38,38',
    left : ' l-20,150 v170',
    bottom : ' h26 v25 c0,30,45,30,45,0 v-25 h200 v25 c0,30,45,30,45,0 v-25 h26',
    right : ' v-170 l-20,-150z',
    // Marquee
    marquee : 'm-60,10 h-182 c-20,0,-20,-25,0,-25 h182 c20,0,20,25,0,25z',
    // Windshield
    windshield : 'm-220,150 c-11,0,-14,-8,-12,-16 l12,-85 c2,-10,5,-17,18,-17 h220 c13,0,17,7,18,17 l12,85, c1,8,-1,16,-12,16 h-235z',
    // Tires
    tire_left : 'm15,100 c0,30,45,30,45,0 c0,-30,-45,-30,-45,0',
    tire_right : 'm180,0 c0,30,45,30,45,0 c0,-30,-45,-30,-45,0',
};

var busIcon = {
    path: 'M0,-100 '+busSvg['top']+busSvg['left']+busSvg['bottom']+busSvg['right']+busSvg['marquee']+busSvg['windshield']+busSvg['tire_left']+busSvg['tire_right'],
    fillColor: "red",
    fillOpacity: 1,
    scale: .3, //.05,
    strokeColor: "black",
    strokeWeight: .5
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fill-rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillRuleProperty) determines what portions of a shape are inside/outside it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Robert.  Looking at the documentation you linked to, I noted that the paths in the circles alternated direction (clockwise and counter-clockwise).  When I modified my paths to do this, I obtained the desired effect without defining a fill-rule.