# Multi-colored Google Map SVG Symbols

Tags: svg, maps

A Google Map marker can take a complex svg path as its icon as in something like:

```
var baseSvg = {
    x1 : "m 0,0 l45,0 l 190,225 l -45,0 l -190,-225 z",
    x2 : "m 225,0 l -45,0 l -190,225 l 45,0 l 190,-225 z"                
};

var baseIcon = {
    path: "M0,0 " + baseSvg["x1"] + baseSvg["x2"],
    fillColor: "#000000",
    fillOpacity: 1,
    scale: .2,
    strokeColor: "black",
    strokeWeight: 0,
    rotation: 15
};
```

which is then fed into a marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(somelat, somelng),
    icon: baseIcon 
});
```

All good. But it only draws in a single colour (black in this example). **So, can they only have a single colour or is there a way to have multi-coloured symbols?** Using the example code, x1 would be red and x2 would be green.

Note that this construct is borrowed from here: [How do I indicate transparency in an SVG path in Google Maps API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13125289/1828610) and it works nicely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a multi color svg icon for google map marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991564/creating-a-multi-color-svg-icon-for-google-map-marker)

Answer (score 1):

I just did the same thing and I think you have to draw two markers with essentially identical data, but with the `path` and in this case `fillColor` properties changed:

```
var baseSvg = {
        x1 : "m 0,0 l45,0 l 190,225 l -45,0 l -190,-225 z",
        x2 : "m 225,0 l -45,0 l -190,225 l 45,0 l 190,-225 z"                
    },
    baseIcon = {
        fillOpacity: 1,
        scale: .2,
        strokeColor: "black",
        strokeWeight: 0,
        rotation: 15
    },
    markerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(somelat, somelng),
    // psuedo code for cloning an object since that 
    // is out of scope for this question
    greenIcon = Object.clone(baseIcon),
    redIcon = Object.clone(baseIcon);

greenIcon.path = baseSvg.x1;
greenIcon.fillColor = "#0f0";
redIcon.path = baseSvg.x2;
redIcon.fillColor = "#f00";

var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerPos,
    map: map,
    icon: greenIcon
});
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerPos, 
    map: map,
    icon: redIcon
});
```

obviously not optimized js, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to opacity, `strokeOpacity` is your guy. Check the [maps.Symbol class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Symbol) for more information on symbol properties.