# Rotate marker on google maps with svg

Tags: google-maps

So, I have read all topics on stack overflow and net regarding this topic.

And I can show marker in desired degree, but what I can not success is to show all "layers" from .svg file.

My svg file is this

```
<svg width="125px" height="74px" viewBox="60 85 125 74" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <defs>
        <rect id="path-1" x="0" y="0" width="105" height="54" rx="4"></rect>
        <filter x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="filter-2">
            <feOffset dx="0" dy="0" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feComposite in="shadowBlurOuter1" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out" result="shadowBlurOuter1"></feComposite>
            <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0.5 0" type="matrix" in="shadowBlurOuter1"></feColorMatrix>
        </filter>
        <mask id="mask-3" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="105" height="54" fill="white">
            <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <g id="Test-Image" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(70.000000, 95.000000)">
        <g id="Test-Box">
            <g id="Background">
                <use fill="black" fill-opacity="1" filter="url(#filter-2)" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
                <use stroke="#FFFFFF" mask="url(#mask-3)" stroke-width="4" fill="#B2005B" fill-rule="evenodd" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
            </g>
            <path d="M82.0839364,42.9141136 L11.2935052,42.9423118 L11.2749164,11.0373262 L82.0839364,11.0419231 L97.9820616,1 L0.444915254,1 L0.444915254,52.9658699 C0.444915254,52.9658699 97.3451506,52.9690943 97.9820616,52.9658699 C98.6189725,52.9626454 82.0839364,42.9141136 82.0839364,42.9141136 Z" id="Test-3D-Shape" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" fill="#D7006E"></path>
        </g>
        <path d="M75.2510488,45.3746213 C75.5223392,45.3746213 75.8817209,45.210132 76.0547854,45.0456428 L85.9943015,35.6908041 C86.4448929,35.2558041 86.4971241,34.5456159 86.0402962,34.0373363 C85.6286832,33.5836267 84.8311832,33.5711535 84.3868284,33.9913417 L76.4204037,41.5009385 L76.4204037,10.2939761 C76.4204037,9.64849225 75.8965327,9.12462128 75.2510488,9.12462128 C74.605565,9.12462128 74.081694,9.64849225 74.081694,10.2939761 L74.081694,41.5009385 L66.1152693,33.9913417 C65.6709144,33.5711535 64.8913445,33.6015568 64.4618015,34.0373363 C64.0080918,34.4972826 64.0478499,35.2612611 64.5077962,35.6908041 L74.4473123,45.0456428 C74.717823,45.3200514 74.9766402,45.371503 75.2510488,45.3746213 Z" id="Page-1" fill="#FFFFFF" transform="translate(75.250000, 27.249621) rotate(-90.000000) translate(-75.250000, -27.249621) "></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

And in google docs say that we need to use paths from svg. But I want to use whole svg file with url (I can see image but can not rotate).

So does anylbody know how to use this file with rotation possibility,
thx

Here is my code

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
  <?=  "center: {lat: ".$order->latitude.", lng: ".$order->longitude."},
     zoom: 11"; ?>
   });

    // //Image rotation
    var symbolOne = {
      path: 'M82.0839364,42.9141136 L11.2935052,42.9423118 L11.2749164,11.0373262 L82.0839364,11.0419231 L97.9820616,1 L0.444915254,1 L0.444915254,52.9658699 C0.444915254,52.9658699 97.3451506,52.9690943 97.9820616,52.9658699 C98.6189725,52.9626454 82.0839364,42.9141136 82.0839364,42.9141136 Z',
      scale: 1,
      strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
      fillColor: '#B2005B',
      fillOpacity: 1
    };

    var symbolTwo = {
      path: 'M75.2510488,45.3746213 C75.5223392,45.3746213 75.8817209,45.210132 76.0547854,45.0456428 L85.9943015,35.6908041 C86.4448929,35.2558041 86.4971241,34.5456159 86.0402962,34.0373363 C85.6286832,33.5836267 84.8311832,33.5711535 84.3868284,33.9913417 L76.4204037,41.5009385 L76.4204037,10.2939761 C76.4204037,9.64849225 75.8965327,9.12462128 75.2510488,9.12462128 C74.605565,9.12462128 74.081694,9.64849225 74.081694,10.2939761 L74.081694,41.5009385 L66.1152693,33.9913417 C65.6709144,33.5711535 64.8913445,33.6015568 64.4618015,34.0373363 C64.0080918,34.4972826 64.0478499,35.2612611 64.5077962,35.6908041 L74.4473123,45.0456428 C74.717823,45.3200514 74.9766402,45.371503 75.2510488,45.3746213 Z',
      scale: 1,
      strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
      fillColor: '#D7006E',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      rotation: 270,
    };

    var symbolThree = {
      path: 'M -1,0 A 1,1 0 0 0 -3,0 1,1 0 0 0 -1,0M 1,0 A 1,1 0 0 0 3,0 1,1 0 0 0 1,0M -3,3 Q 0,5 3,3',
      strokeColor: '#00F',
      rotation: 45
    };

    var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: [{lat: <?=$order->latitude?>, lng: <?=$order->longitude?>}, {lat: <?=$order->latitude?>, lng: <?=$order->longitude?>}],
  icons: [
    {
      icon: symbolOne,
      offset: '0%'
    }, {
      icon: symbolTwo,
      offset: '0%'
    }],
  map: map
});

marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
  position: {
    lat:  <?=$order->latitude?>,
    lng: <?=$order->longitude?>
  },
  map: map,
  labelContent: "<?=$order->id?>",
  labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 0),
  labelClass: "mapLabels", // the CSS class for the label
  labelStyle: {opacity: 0.8},
});
```

Comment: Related question: [rotate a .gif image on google maps api v3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723573/rotate-a-gif-image-on-google-maps-api-v3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the complete SVG icon (with all its paths), save it as a file, then use that as the URL for the marker.

Related question: [Creating a multi color svg icon for google map marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991564/creating-a-multi-color-svg-icon-for-google-map-marker)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbopu529/1/)

You can then rotate it as explained in [rotate a .gif image on google maps api v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723573/rotate-a-gif-image-on-google-maps-api-v3)

[proof of concept fiddle with rotating marker](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wbopu529/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    icon: {
      url: "https://www.geocodezip.net/mapIcons/SO_20170123_svgMarker.svg",
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(62.5, 37),
    },
    labelContent: "27",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 8),
    labelClass: "mapLabels", // the CSS class for the label
    labelStyle: {
      opacity: 0.8,
      color: "white"
    },
    title: "svg url"
  });

  var symbolOne = {
    path: 'M82.0839364,42.9141136 L11.2935052,42.9423118 L11.2749164,11.0373262 L82.0839364,11.0419231 L97.9820616,1 L0.444915254,1 L0.444915254,52.9658699 C0.444915254,52.9658699 97.3451506,52.9690943 97.9820616,52.9658699 C98.6189725,52.9626454 82.0839364,42.9141136 82.0839364,42.9141136 Z',
    scale: 1,
    strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
    fillColor: '#B2005B',
    fillOpacity: 1
  };
  var marker2 = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: {
      lat: 37.454476,
      lng: -122.11617
    },
    map: map,
    icon: symbolOne,
    labelContent: "27",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 8),
    labelClass: "mapLabels", // the CSS class for the label
    labelStyle: {
      opacity: 0.8,
      color: "white"
    },
    title: "svg symbol"
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
.mapLabels {
  color: "white"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/fb56a0dc/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<img src="https://www.geocodezip.net/mapIcons/SO_20170123_svgMarker.svg" />
```