# How to rotate a marker in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Following is the code to rotate a marker, but how to rotate a custom marker. Any Idea?

```
var angleDegrees = 150;
new google.maps.Marker({
    position: a,
    map: map,
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        scale: 6,
        fillColor: "red",
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        rotation: angleDegrees //this is how to rotate the pointer
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Symbol) doesn't say anything specifically about how rotation is accomplished but since `path` takes an SVG-element I'd say thats how they manage to rotate it. If you create your custom marker using SVG it can be done quite easily using [`transform="rotate(deg centerX centerY")`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute).

Comment: Thanks, I found this **The symbol's path, which is a built-in symbol path, or a custom path expressed using SVG path notation.**

Comment: Precisely, so you could add your own SVG-symbols using that. HEre is an example of the syntax needed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125289/how-do-i-indicate-transparency-in-an-svg-path-in-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: Is there no other method we can rotate any custom image? in the above example you can write url: 'path' of custom image but its not rotating.

Comment: There are a few ways that come to mind, mostly using [canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951711/how-to-rotate-a-marker-in-google-maps/18951899?noredirect=1#comment28061537_18951899) or [css3 transforms](http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate) but the support in browsers (older ones in particular) varies quite a bit.

Answer (score 25):

rotation is available within the API.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-custom

```
var icon = {
    ...
    path: '...',
    scale: 1,
    rotation: [degrees]
};

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: [...],
  icon: icon,
  ...
});
```

Comment: That works only for custom symbols in SVG format and with therefore a path

Comment: To update rotation on an existing icon, you need to call the setter, e.g. `myMarker.icon.rotation++;myMarker.setIcon(myMarker.icon)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to rotate an image, element is the image and degree is the angle you would like to rotate, zero is when an arrow is up to the north:

```
function (element, degree) {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match("Chrome")) {
       element.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(" + degree + "deg)";
    }
    else if (navigator.userAgent.match("Firefox")) {
       element.style.MozTransform = "rotate(" + degree + "deg)";
    }
    else if (navigator.userAgent.match("MSIE")) {
       element.style.msTransform = "rotate(" + degree + "deg)";
    }
    else if (navigator.userAgent.match("Opera")) {
       element.style.OTransform = "rotate(" + degree + "deg)";
    }
    else {
       element.style.transform = "rotate(" + degree + "deg)";
    }
}
```

Best regards,

Chen

Comment: Your code is outdated. Firefox (16+) and IE (10+) don't use prefixes anymore, and Opera 15+ uses the webkit prefix.

Comment: @Chen: Sorry I'm unable to get you, I have to use that custom marker multiple times and all do not have same direction.

Comment: How do you get the marker element?

Comment: This code is outdated. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083056/css-what-are-moz-and-webkit/38651165#38651165) as why it is.