# How to rotate marker in Nokia HERE javascript API?

Tags: javascript, marker, here-api

I'm using Nokia HERE javascript library to put a marker on the map. I'm using a png image to create an icon for marker. I'm able to see the marker/image/icon on map successfully after following the documentation here - 
http://developer.here.com/api-explorer#maps-js/create-dom-marker

Next, I would like to rotate this marker by few degrees. I see similar feature in Google Maps as posted here - [How to rotate a marker in Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951711/how-to-rotate-a-marker-in-google-maps) but I don't see any way to supply rotation in degrees in HERE APIs. So is there any way to rotate a marker in Nokia HERE Javascript framework? A sample code or fiddle example would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transform property to simply rotate the marker you have created. For example on the example http://developer.here.com/api-explorer#maps-js/create-dom-marker something like the following should do the trick

```
innerElement.style.webkitTransform='rotate(90deg)';
innerElement.style.msTransform='rotate(90deg)';
innerElement.style.transform='rotate(90deg)';
```