# how to rotate google custom marker in angular 2

Tags: angular, google-maps

i am developing track Live application in that i have to show deviation for marker with certain angles (like ola  app Marker deviation) .i searched in net but i am getting in java script(even though i am not getting deviation to my marker)

i tried like in my html

```
 <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat_pick" [label]="'P'" [longitude]="lng_pick" [rotation]=50></sebm-google-map-marker>
```

but i am getting an error

> rotaion is not know property of sebm-global-map

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://angular-maps.com/docs/api/latest/ts/core/SebmGoogleMap-directive.html) of sebm google maps and also in your error message, "rotation" is not property of sebm-google-map.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951711/how-to-rotate-a-marker-in-google-maps) answer which might help you to achieve marker rotation.

Comment: the link is java script.but i am using angular 2 google maps.u r link is not related to my code .if any code which is in angular 2 please let me know