# Rotate/modify a png image in Google Maps with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to rotate my google.maps.Marker to follow the route correctly, Uber-like. When I use a simple SVG, with a single path, it works perfectly, but now I'm using an image (.png) and nothing happens. The image appears on the screen, follow the route, but it doesn't animate at all.

Do you guys know any solution for my problem? I need a smooth transition between streets, turns and etc. Thank you in advance.

PS: Now I'll try to make it with canvas and the lib Box2D JS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951711/how-to-rotate-a-marker-in-google-maps

Comment: try this example https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3b3j61pq/4/