# How to rotate marker in rails using gmaps4rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, marker, gmaps4rails

I have set car as a marker and want to rotate it. Is there any way to rotate it in the defined code. If not, what other options do I have?

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({
    provider: {},
    internal: {
        id: "map"
    }
}, function() {
    marker = handler.addMarkers([{
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
        "picture": {
            "url": "/assets/car.png",
            "width": 17,
            "height": 38
        }
    }]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29411992/7365329) answer. It uses the canvas to rotate the image. See the jsfiddle link for live example at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this question:

[How to rotate a marker in Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951711/how-to-rotate-a-marker-in-google-maps)

path takes an SVG-element I'd say thats how they manage to rotate it. If you create your custom marker using SVG it can be done quite easily using

```
transform="rotate(deg centerX centerY").
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I followed the link and set `icon: "/assets/car.png" ` and applied rotation using `rotation: 45` but it's not rotating. When I set the `icon: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW`, it rotates perfectly. And I didn't get the `transform` part.